Como aumentar tamaño letra de escala en matplotlib
Quiero aumentar el tamaños de la letra de escalado, me refiero a las letras que salen arriba a la izquierda de la ventana de gráfico en maplotlib que indica la escala, algo como esto: le-5

He hecho un gráfico grande y queda muy pequeño, querría aumentarlo pero no he encontrado la manera.
Toda ayuda se agradece!
Xavier,

Matplotlib concretamente llama al multiplicador "offset".
Primero un ejemplo:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(0, 10**8, 10**2), range(0, 10**8, 10**2))

plt.show()


Puedes obtener una referencia del objeto mediante matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_offset_text(), es un objeto Text, por lo que simplemente puedes usar su método set_fontsize():
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca() # Obtener una referencia al eje
ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(17)
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(17)

plt.plot(range(0, 10**8, 10**2), range(0, 10**8, 10**2))

plt.show()

También puede usar la propiedad directamente:
ax.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(17)
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(17)



Muy agradecido FJSevilla !
